# How i can send data from Login to SQLite?

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to perform a user registration, in order to store the user data, the password must go through a verification. I need a little help with that as I am starting with Xamarin and I don't really understand

The fields "Usuario" and "Contra2" or "Contra1" (It does not matter since they must be the same) are the ones that I want to send to the database created in SQLite

This is my code from NuevoUsuario.xaml

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
         <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:Custom="clr-namespace:ViniloAdmin.Custom"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:ViniloAdmin.ViewModel"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="ViniloAdmin.NuevoUsuario">

             <ContentPage.BindingContext>
             <viewmodel:VinilosModel/>
             </ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <Grid>
        <Image Source="fondoapp3.png" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
        <Image Source="discovinilo.png" x:Name="logo" Margin="83,0,82,440"></Image>
        <Button x:Name="Guardar" Margin="125,560,125,15" ImageSource="guardar.png" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="Guardar_Clicked" Command="{Binding InsertarUsuario}"></Button>
        <Button x:Name="btnvolver" Margin="356,10,1,589" ImageSource="btnvolver.png" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="btnvolver_Clicked"></Button>

        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="Start">
            <Custom:SimpleEntry Placeholder="NOMBRE DE USUARIO" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="NombreUsuario" FontSize="20"
                   TextColor="Black" PlaceholderColor="Black" Margin="50,355,50,0"
                                IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnableText}" Text="{Binding Login.Usuario}" ></Custom:SimpleEntry>
            
            <Custom:SimpleEntry Placeholder="CONTRASEÑA" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="Contra1" FontSize="20"
                   TextColor="Black" PlaceholderColor="Black" Margin="50,17,50,0" IsPassword="true"
                                IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnableText}"  ></Custom:SimpleEntry>
            
            <Custom:SimpleEntry Placeholder="REPETIR CONTRASEÑA" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="Contra2" FontSize="20"
                   TextColor="Black" PlaceholderColor="Black" Margin="50,17,50,0" IsPassword="true"
                                IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnableText}" Text="{Binding Login.Pass}"></Custom:SimpleEntry>
            
        </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

And this is my code from NuevoUsuario.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using ViniloAdmin.Models;
using ViniloAdmin.ViewModel;
using SQLite;

namespace ViniloAdmin
{
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class NuevoUsuario : ContentPage
{
    
public NuevoUsuario()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    
    
}

async void btnvolver_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MainPage());
}

async void Guardar_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    
    if (this.NombreUsuario.Text != null && this.Contra1.Text != null && this.Contra2.Text != null)
    {
        if (this.Contra1.Text != this.Contra2.Text)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Advertencia", "Las contraseñas no coinciden", "Cerrar");
        }
        else
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Listo", "Registro exitoso", "Cerrar");
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MainPage());
        }
        
    }
    else
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Advertencia", "Faltan campos por llenar", "Cerrar");
    }
}
```

}
}

> I think that i need to send into this

```
else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Listo", "Registro exitoso", "Cerrar");
                await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MainPage());
            }
```

But I dont know how. And i know that

```
Text="{Binding Login.Pass}" Text="{Binding Login.Usuario}
```

not is correct. Since it sends the data that is in the fields without before going through the verification inside the "if" in the button function.

If it is of any use here I leave the function inside the ViewModel.cs

```
public Command InsertarUsuario
{
    get
    {
        return new Command(() =>
        {
            this.repou.InsertarUsuario(this.Login.ID, Login.Usuario, Login.Pass);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: your button's have both Clicked handlers and Commands defined.  You usually only do one or the other, not both.  For example, if you use just the clicked handler then you can add your code do insert in the db inside your else block

Comment: Hmmm I dont know how to fix it

Comment: @JoséAndrésAlay, as Jason said , you either use button click or button command, you can only choose one of them. If you use both of them, just fire Button_click event, so  InsertarUsuario will be not fired.

Comment: I do some chance in my project, please check my comment and leave me your opinion. Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove Command from your Button xaml  by merging it in your Clicked event handler (Guardar_Clicked)

2. Delete it from your view model as not needed anymore:
   Delete this code

```
public Command InsertarUsuario
{
    get
    {
        return new Command(() =>
        {
            this.repou.InsertarUsuario(this.Login.ID, Login.Usuario, Login.Pass);
        });
    }
}
```

3. Now call `repou.InsertarUsuario()` which defined in `VinilosModel` class from your Guardar_Clicked:

```
async void Guardar_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.NombreUsuario.Text != null && this.Contra1.Text != null && this.Contra2.Text != null)
    {
        if (this.Contra1.Text != this.Contra2.Text)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Advertencia", "Las contraseñas no coinciden", "Cerrar");
        }
        else
        {
            (BindingContext as VinilosModel).repou.InsertarUsuario((BindingContext as VinilosModel).Login.ID, Login.Usuario, Login.Pass);
            await DisplayAlert("Listo", "Registro exitoso", "Cerrar");
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MainPage());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Advertencia", "Faltan campos por llenar", "Cerrar");
    }
}
```

Not sure but I guess InsertarUsuario is sync thus you need to await it as well.

Comment: I try to do it but i have error in else:

1. VinilosModel.repou is inaccessible due to its protection level
2 and 3. An object reference is requered for the non-static field, method, or property Login.Usuario and Login.Pass

Comment: Thanks you, your comment helped me find the solution, you can see it in my comment on this post

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your support. I solved it based on Cfun answer, I just made these changes in NuevoUsuario.xaml.cs

```
public partial class NuevoUsuario : ContentPage
    {
       RepositoryVinilos repou;
        public NuevoUsuario()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new VinilosModel();
            this.repou = new RepositoryVinilos();
            this.repou.CrearBBDD();
        }

        async void btnvolver_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MainPage());
        }

        async void Guardar_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var bbddfile = "Datos.db3";
            var rutadocumentos = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            var path = Path.Combine(rutadocumentos, bbddfile);
            SQLiteConnection cn = new SQLiteConnection(path);

            if (this.NombreUsuario.Text != null && this.Contra1.Text != null && this.Contra2.Text != null)
            {
                if (this.Contra1.Text != this.Contra2.Text)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Advertencia", "Las contraseñas no coinciden", "Cerrar");
                }
                else
                {
                    var item = new Login()
                    {
                        Usuario = NombreUsuario.Text,
                        Pass = Contra1.Text,
                    };
                    cn.Insert(item);
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                    {
                        await this.DisplayAlert("Listo", "Registro exitoso", "Cerrar");
                        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MainPage());
                    });
                    
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Advertencia", "Faltan campos por llenar", "Cerrar");
            }
        }
    }
```